# HTML load before my js function executes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If my controller, I have a function to set the true to a variable.

```
function setShow() {
  return this.isShow === 'Foo';
}
```

My this.isShow is 'Foo'

In my template, I have `<div ng-if = "vm.setShow()"> Hi </div>`

But it seems like that HTML load before my js function executes? I do not know how to handle this case. I often face this problem.

Comment: You should not have side-effects in if functions.

Comment: Please add your full controller and view.

Comment: Ok. Let me ask, template load first, or JS functions load first?

Comment: what is the problem? also ng-if should be an expression that returns true/false. for example ng-if="isShow"

Comment: Problem is. It suppose to show <div>, but it does not

Comment: @SLaks What do you mean? I did not get.  Let me ask, template load first, or JS functions load first?

Comment: that is because your function doesn't return true

Comment: <div ng-if="isShow'" 
     ng-init="someMethod()">
</div>, you can't call a method directly with ng-if

Comment: @JinnaBalu you definitely can call a method directly with ng-if

Comment: I think what you are trying to ask about is handled by `ng-cloak`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

From [ng-if](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp):

> The ng-if directive removes the HTML element if the expression
>   evaluates to false.
>
> If the if statement evaluates to true, a copy of the Element is added
>   in the DOM.

your function doesn't evaluate to true and that is why the div isn't show. try returning true from the function.

Edit: now that you edited your post, the problem seems to be the function isn't in $scope and there is a strange vm in ng-if that probably shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:

In angularjs:
But $timeout service should be inject into your controller.

```
 $timeout(function(){
// write your logic here
 },100);
```

This will fire when your HTML document is ready.
Call your function inside the timeout.

Or in JavaScript you can use the:

```
   Settimeout(function(){
   //write here
  },100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the setShow function declared in the *$scope*. I think the *ng-if* directive doesn't find the function and it interprets as false. 
Try

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    
   
   var isShow = "Foo";
    
    $scope.setShow = function () {
        return isShow == "Foo";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-if="setShow()"> Hi </div>
   
</div>
```